# jquery html insert not showing up in source code so downstream event handlers don't work?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to make a jquery script where if you click a checkbox the values are appended to a div and if you want to remove values from the div you can click it and a lightbox with the selected checkboxes show up.

this is the html markup

this is the lightbox

this is the div which leads to the lightbox

```
<div id="fasta_reader" class="hidden" style="height: 500px; width: 200px; border:2px solid #000000;">

<div id="test_boxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="Car">I have a car <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="gel">I have a gel <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="gol">I have a gol<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="feet">I have a feet<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="hand">I have a hand <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="ear">I have a ear<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkers" value="nose">I have a nose <br>
</div>
```

the first event i.e. '.checkers' onclick send/remove div value is working fine.
the second event div onclick fire up lightbox is working as well

here is the jquery for the first event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.checkers').click(function(){
if (this.checked) 
{
var div_val = $.trim($("#fasta_reader").text());
var check_val = $(this).val();
var box_val = '<span class="box_breaks"><input type="checkbox"class="lightbox_checkbox" name="lightbox_val" id='+check_val+'_checkbox'+' value='+check_val+'>'+check_val+'</input></span>';
var div_class = $("#fasta_reader").attr("class");
if(div_val == "" && div_class == "hidden")
{
var new_val = div_val + check_val;
$("#fasta_reader").removeClass("hidden");
$("#fasta_reader").append(new_val);
}
else if(div_val != "" && div_class != "hidden")
{
var new_val = " "+check_val;
$("#fasta_reader").append(new_val);
}
$('.box').append(box_val);
$("#"+check_val+"_checkbox").prop('checked',true);
}
else if(!(this.checked))
{
var check_val = $(this).val();
var div_val_index = $.trim($("#fasta_reader").text()).indexOf(check_val);
var div_val = $.trim($("#fasta_reader").text());
var box_id = "#"+check_val+'_checkbox';
$(box_id).parent('span').remove();

if(div_val_index > 0)
{
var new_val = div_val.replace(" "+check_val, "");
$("#fasta_reader").text(new_val);
}
else
{
div_val = div_val.replace(check_val, "");
$("#fasta_reader").text(div_val);
}
}
if(div_val == "" && div_class != "hidden")
{
$("#fasta_reader").addClass("hidden");
}

});
});
```

and this is the code for the lightbox onclick event handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.lightbox_checkbox').click(function(){
            alert("HEHE");
            if(!(this.checked))
            {
            $("#test_boxes input:checkbox[value="+this_val+"]").attr("checked", false);
            }
            else if(this.checked)
            {
            $("#test_boxes input:checkbox[value="+this_val+"]").attr("checked", true);
            }
            });
            });
```

this is the event which is not working I tried changing document ready to .lightbox_checkbox load function but it did not work,

I removed the if else statements as well but the alert just won't fire up. Why is the alert statement not firing up?

I also that none of the html inserts which i did with jquery actually showed up in the source code of my page

so is it possible that as the content does not exist physically the code fails to work?

I ask because both the html inserts i.e. lightbox and #fasta_reader are loaded by clicking the physical content of the page. So in actuality both these elements are visually linked to each other but physically linked to the content present on the page.

Please advise if I am right in this regard, and what is a possible solution to making the the process work i.e. jquery generated lightbox checkbox onclick start event

Comment: can you post into a jsfiddle?

Comment: here's the fiddle Sam 
http://jsfiddle.net/NcMSn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For variable box_val do not use the plain html directly.
Instead create DOM elements to insert the HTML values using $.html().

I am using like :

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
td1.setAttribute("align","center");
$(td1).html(executeFormatter());
tr.appendChild(td1);
$("#tableBody").append(tr);
```

my executeFormatter looks like :

```
function executeFormatter(){
    return html = "<span onclick=\"clickFunc()\" class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\" ></span>";
}
```

And is working perfectly for me.

Regards,
Amit